# Does software exist: Schedule a series of web pages to be displayed on a screen?

Tags: browser, display, scheduled-tasks

I have a requirement to **display a series of webpages** on a large screen running from a dedicated Windows computer.

I want to **display each webpage for a specific period of time** before moving onto the next webpage.

Does there any any software or service that provides this?

Comment: Do they have to be live? Or could it be a screen shot of the site?

Comment: It needs to be live - as the pages shown are many dashboards display the status of various systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I purchased http://www.e-motional.com/autowebview.htm which allows this functionality as a screensaver.

Answer (score 1):

*You've not listed how the computer is set up or what software is available, so this is a stab in the dark.*

If you have or can use PowerPoint, there is an Add In called [LiveWeb](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm#.UPVgsqytl_g) which allows you to view web pages in the presentation in real time.

> Use LiveWeb to insert web pages into a PowerPoint slide and refresh
>   the pages real-time during slide show. Display web pages without ever
>   leaving the confines of your PowerPoint slide show. No coding
>   required.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up the browser on that machine to display each webpage in a different browser tab, so that hitting "ctrl-tab" will rotate to the next page.  Then I'd use AutoIT or AutoHotkey to send the "ctrl-tab" key every "x" seconds.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion - but we need to show each webpage for a different period of time and ideally it needs to be easy to change the schedule through a UI

Comment: Your AutoIT/AutoHotkey could be set up that way, though it would be a littly tricky.  You'd have each webpage set up as a favorite, and have AutoIT send the appropriate keystrokes to choose whichever favorite from the list.  (Something like "Alt-A,downarrow,downarrow,Enter")  You could create a gui to control it or use a config file.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly idea:

Use windows task scheduler to start a new browser displaying that webpage.

Most browsers allow you to specify the startpage like this 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"  http://superuser.com/`

T+0:     Start webpage 1
T+10min  Kill all browser processes, start a new browser with webpage 2
T+12min  Kill all browser processes, start a new browser with webpage 3
etc etc

To kill the browser you could use `taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe*`.

Personally I find this an ugly way to do it, but it seems one way to accomplish your task.

A much neater way would be something like creating a single webpage, display that. Use javascript to periodically refresh the webpage (where each refresh loads from a different page). Much cleaner, but the person maintaining that will need to understand how webpages and or javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

Vue Pilot does what you're looking for. You can create rotation lists that are synchronised between all your screens and manage them from an online interface.  Makes it super easy to update a bunch of screens at once instead of doing them manually.

Allows for auto start on boot up, remote management etc

Check it out
https://www.vuepilot.com